# Can we set the heading and rotation of a Google Maps Embed street view using the UI's provided by Google?

Tags: google-maps

Embedded Google Maps street views are no longer working on a client's side because the response from maps.google.com includes a `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header.

I've attempted to use Google's Maps Embed API page (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) so that this client can generate these street views automatically for a given address, but the results from this page have the street view camera angled at a completely different address, and rotating the camera is never captured in the final URL that is generated.

Is there a recommended way of capturing a street view embed link that includes heading / rotation now that embedding directly from maps.google.com doesn't work? I should point out that these can be set by hand, but it would require transcribing them from the normal maps.google.com UI into these new generated embed URLs.

Answer (score 1):

The [Embed API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#street_view_mode) defines the following optional parameters:

> The following URL parameters are optional:
>
> **heading** indicates the compass heading of the camera in degrees clockwise from North. Accepted values are from -180° to 360&deg.
>
> **pitch** specifies the angle, up or down, of the camera. The pitch is specified in degrees from -90° to 90°. Positive values will angle the camera up, while negative values will angle the camera down. The default pitch of 0° is set based on on the position of the camera when the image was captured. Because of this, a pitch of 0° is often, but not always, horizontal. For example, an image taken on a hill will likely exhibit a default pitch that is not horizontal.
>
> **fov** determines the horizontal field of view of the image. The field of view is expressed in degrees, with a range of 10° - 100°. It defaults to 90°. When dealing with a fixed-size viewport the field of view is can be considered the zoom level, with smaller numbers indicating a higher level of zoom.

[Adding those to the request works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map3.html) (the wizard just doesn't create them for me)

Comment: Totally, and as I said in my question I understand that those can be set by hand. I'm trying to determine whether or not these can be captured via the Google Maps embed UI in any way.

Comment: What do you mean by "captured via the Google Maps embed UI"?  How are you creating the Embed API URLs?  If I enter an address, it just works for me.

Comment: I was referring to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start. The street view image is, for me, never rotated facing the address entered and when I do make changes to the street view camera position the generated embed URL doesn't reflect the heading, pitch, or fov changes.

Comment: I've just found that the traditional UI (google.com/maps) has an option to share an "Embed Image", which is really not an image at all but an embeddable URL for the street view (with current heading et al) that doesn't send the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header. This will work great for the end-user in my original question. Thanks for your info, @geocodezip.